# Can I use a no-arg constructor with Hazelcast Portable?

Tags: hazelcast

The Hazelcast documentation on their Portable serialization mechanism says that you are not forced to use a no-arg constructor.

https://hazelcast.org/mastering-hazelcast/#serialization-start

But their example code shows fields being set directly.

```
@Override
public void readPortable(PortableReader reader) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("Deserialize");
    this.name = reader.readUTF("name");
}
```

and the factory used to create instances of the class being deserialized is using a no-arg constructor.

```
@Override
public Portable create(int classId) {
    switch (classId) {
        case PERSON_CLASS_ID:
           return new Person();
    }
    return null;
 }
```

Am I right in assuming that you are not forced to use a no-arg constructor but you can't use it to set field values when deserializing? How would you handle enforcing invariants such as never-null fields and how would you deserialize a subclass without making the fields in the superclass protected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While deserializing you can't maintain invariants since the object is being reconstructed; so some fields are just not set. There is no point resisting this.

And you are not forced to have a no-arg constructor. As long as the factory can create an instance, HZ doesn't care how you create it.

Comment: Right you can put the factory into the same package and make the no-arg constructor package private and only argument constructors checking for invariants in publicly available constructors.